# Use VBA to hide queries and modules in MS Access and prevent user access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

How do i hide all queries/Modules from left hand side of the Access objects in order to prevent user to access them.

Answer (score 0):

You can make objects hidden by `right clicking on object>View Properties > Attributes: Hidden = True`

you can hide the navigation pane by going to `File>Options>Current Database>Navigation>uncheck the 'Display Navigation Pane" box`

And you can hide most of the stuff on the ribbon by `File>Options>Current Database>Ribbon and Toolbar options> uncheck "Allow Full Menus"`

The problem with all of this is that none of it is permanent. Any user can show the navigation pane by hitting `F11` or show full menus by right clicking on the quick access toolbar and getting into the access options.

You can automatically do all of this on startup using an autoexec macro but again, a clever person can get around all of it.

Comment: It is also possible for users to display hidden items and system items.  You can disable special keys that prevents F11 from working.

Comment: Totally agree @MontyWild. There is no completely locking down an Access file. Even compiling to accde is reversible and at that doesn't lock down queries. Then there's the whole hold down shift at start up trick... If you need total control Access is not the tool for you.

Comment: Compiling to accde is not reversible, as far as the code modules are concerned.

Comment: Combining this method with compiling to accde is generally enough to keep all but the most determined user out. My policy is, if we lock down and make an accde and someone gets around it, my manager needs to consider giving them an interview.

Comment: @parakmiakos, true it's not easily reversible. (I was thinking of accdr when I wrote that). All this stuff adds up though. Access is enough of a black box to most people that obfuscation is often enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could compile your Access app into an 'MDE' or 'ACCDE' (compiled executable) file: http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Creating_MDE,_ADE,_and_ACCDE_Files